# contineously writing to text file and deleting old data after fixed timer

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qtextstream

In Qt I'm writing continuously to text file, so my file size increasing but i want kept size limit so need to delete old data in text file.

I calculating file size in MB for every minute if file size is greater than 600MB I used QFile::resize(100); now file size is 100MB but data is older only , I wanted after resize data should be latest written to file.

Comment: Use a fixed size circular buffer and keep a pointer to the current position. As you add to the end it will overwrite. To print the file, start at the pointer and skip the first line fragment.

Comment: @stark As per your suggestion it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems do not support cutting a file at the beginning. Most common solution for big log files is to close the file, rename it and create a new file.